# Cannot make circle radius by dividing the length of a line and setting it as radius

Tags: python, graphics

I need to set the radius of the circle I am making to be 1/4 of the size from a length of a line that was made earlier.

```
win = GraphWin("Interactive Drawing",300,300)
win.setCoords(0,0,300,300)

##Create instruction to click the corners of the rectangle
instruction1 = Text(Point(104,10), "Click for lower left of rectangle")
instruction1.draw(win)
lowerLeft = win.getMouse()
instruction1.undraw()
instruction2 = Text(Point(100,10), "Click upper right of rectangle")
instruction2.draw(win)
upperRight = win.getMouse()
instruction2.undraw()

##Draw 2 triangles to form a multicolor rectangle from given points

rightX = upperRight.getX()
rightY = upperRight.getY()

leftX = lowerLeft.getX()
leftY = lowerLeft.getY()

leftZ = rightY - leftY
leftB = leftY + leftZ

rightZ = rightY - leftZ

point1 = Point(leftX,leftY)
point2 = Point(leftX,leftB)
point3 = Point(rightX,rightY)
point4 = Point(rightX,rightZ)


leftTriangle = Polygon(point1,point2,point3)
leftTriangle.draw(win)
leftTriangle.setFill("Purple")

rightTriangle = Polygon(point1,point3,point4)
rightTriangle.draw(win)
rightTriangle.setFill("Green")

##Get Circle point from mouse and draw 4 from point

color = Entry(Point(90,30),19)
color.setText("Enter Color Name Here")
color.draw(win)
instruction3 = Text(Point(114,10), "Click location after entering color")
instruction3.draw(win)
circleClick = win.getMouse()
instruction3.undraw()

circleX = circleClick.getX
circleY = circleClick.getY
circleCenter = Point(circleX,circleY)

radius = ((rightY - leftY)/4)

circle1 = Circle(circleCenter, radius)
circle1.draw(win)
circle2 = Circle(300 - circleClick.getX, 300 - circleClick.getY,radius)
circle2.draw(win)
```

When I run the program, I am able to make the rectangle, but when asking for a mouse click point to be the center of the circle and trying to draw it, I get the error

```
  File "C:/Users/Ian/Documents/Python Projects/InputDrawing.py", line 68, in main
    circle1 = Circle(circleCenter, radius)
  File "C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\graphics.py", line 599, in __init__
    p1 = Point(center.x-radius, center.y-radius)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'method' and 'float'
```

I am not sure how to change them into things that can be divided together to get a radius for the circle. Any help? (If this makes any sense haha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few times throughout the code, you use `.getX` or `.getY`. This means you're getting the *functions* `getX` and `getY`, instead of the values `x` and `y`.

To fix this, call the functions with ().

The current cause of your error are these lines:

```
circleX = circleClick.getX
circleY = circleClick.getY
```

Switch them to:

```
circleX = circleClick.getX()
circleY = circleClick.getY()
```

You also need to change the line:

```
circle2 = Circle(300 - circleClick.getX, 300 - circleClick.getY,radius)
```

to:

```
circle2 = Circle(300 - circleClick.getX(), 300 - circleClick.getY(),radius)
```

This line isn't currently causing problems for you, but it will once you fix the first bug.

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with the library you're working with, so I don't know for sure. Does Circle have a setFill() method? It looks like that's what you use to set the color of the Triangles.

Comment: Ahh sorry, deleted comment because I figured it out. Needed to change the inside of setFill() to be setFill(color.getText))